# AMD R7 M265 Hybrid Graphic Card can't download driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx

I have Intel/AMD R7 M265 Hybrid Graphic Card and I am working on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

I am trying to setup AMD Drivers but it is not working. It always give to me same error.
After I setup `fglrx` or `fglrx-update`, I reboot my computer but my Ubuntu is not opening. I always get error like wrong display card.

When i wrote `lspci` I got this:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] (rev ff)
```

How i can solve this problem ? Do you have any suggestion for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest AMD driver for your card from here. [AMD R7 M265 Driver download page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064)

Detailed instructions for installing on Ubuntu 14.04 are given here. [AMD Linux installation instructions](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my late acknowledgment, but I have tried this a lot of times I can say on my PC this is not working. After installing AMD Drivers, I can't access my Ubuntu. I have to open PC in Recovery mode and delete drivers again.